# Committing records inserted by a stored procedure in Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird

I created the following Stored Procedure

```
SET TERM ^ ;  
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE EDIT_FATURA (fat_id integer, mflag integer) as 
begin     
  update inv_lines set mflag = :mflag where fat_id = :fat_id;
  delete from inv_lines_temp where 1=1 ;     
  insert into inv_lines_temp select ID,CODE_ID,ADET,UNIT_PRICE,LINE_NET,LINE_VAT,KDV,LINE_GRAND,CRN 
from inv_lines where fat_id = :fat_id; 
end^  
SET TERM ; ^  
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE ON INV_LINES TO PROCEDURE EDIT_FATURA;  
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE ON INV_LINES_TEMP TO PROCEDURE EDIT_FATURA;  
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE EDIT_FATURA TO SYSDBA;
```

And with the following code I call the stored procedure with my Delphi application

```
dm.q_genel.Close;     
dm.q_genel.SQL.Clear;     
dm.q_genel.SQL.Add('EXECUTE PROCEDURE EDIT_FATURA(:p1,:p2)');
dm.q_genel.ParamByName('p1').AsInteger := fid;
dm.q_genel.ParamByName('p1').AsInteger := sayi; 
dm.q_genel.execute;
```

As it is seen, some records inserted to a table by stored procedure called in my delphi application.

But since they are not committed after the execution of the stored procedure, I cannot access newly inserted records in my application.

How i can commit rows inserted by Stored Procedure so that i can access them in my application?

As far as i know, it is not allows "commit" within a Stored Procedure

Answer (score 5):

You must start a transaction, run the stored procedure and then commit or rollback if any errors. This is done in the application, so your code would look like this:

```
 begin
    dm.q_genel.Close;     
    dm.q_genel.SQL.Clear;     
    dm.q_genel.SQL.Add('EXECUTE PROCEDURE EDIT_FATURA(:p1,:p2)');
    dm.q_genel.ParamByName('p1').AsInteger := fid;
    dm.q_genel.ParamByName('p1').AsInteger := sayi; 
    try
      dm.<Database>.StartTransaction;
      dm.q_genel.execute;
      dm.<Database>.Commit;
    except
      dm.<Database>.Rollback;
      raise;
    end;      
  end;
```

Or if you want to read the records before the commit so you can rollback in certain circumstances, you can change the **isolation level** in the database so you can read the record, of course, only **you** or your app could read it, nobody else can read it until you make a commit.